# How to handle Google API SHA-1 Certificate Authentication to allow multiple users?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, certificate, sha1

For our senior project, four of my classmates and I have teamed up to build an Android app that uses Google Maps.

So far everything is going fine, but we have hit one issue that we are not sure how to work around.

When using the Maps API, you sign up for an API key that is assigned to the program we are creating. In order to authenticate the API key on the Google Developer console, it must be associated with an SHA-1 certification, which appears to be generated by our JDK. It would seem that, even though all five of us are working on the same project, we all have different SHA-1 certifications.

1. Is it possible for all of us to use a single SHA-1 certification for our project, even though we are on different computers and phones, so that we don’t need to go through the process of discovering each of our individual certifications and registering them?
2. How do we get around this certification issue once we are prepared to publish the app (or at least share it with our other classmates for testing)? Clearly I can not take the time register each of my 40 classmates’ certifications individually, and once we release this to the public there will be no way to do so. How does one get around this?

I’ve searched on the Google API documentation pages about this, and there is plenty of information about the API key, but surprisingly little about the SHA-1 certification, which is an equally important aspect of authentication.

I've also searched on this site and found similar questions, but most of them seem to involve user credentials (IE login and password). At this time, the only credentials we are using is a Facebook login (via the FB API) so I don't think that is relevant (though I may be wrong).

Thank you so much for your time and wisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the SHA-1 fingerprint is generated by the keystore used to sign the builds. The default debug keystore located in the android home directory is different on every computer. You can either add the fingerprints from all the the debug keystores you are using or share the same keystore file.

Sharing the same keystore can be easily be done by storing it inside the project folder and then referencing it with the gradle build file with the signingConfig. see [example](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations)

The other easy solution is to add everyone's SHA-1 fingerprint in the Google Cloud console for Google Maps API project you have setup.